# Why is there a helicopter flying over Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

There is a helicopter flying over Arkham City. What is the purpose of it?

It is also possible to grapple on it. Will I ever need this helicopter in my missions in the game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Tyger helicopters are there for Tyger to keep control of the city.

> When Protocol 10 is enacted, their purpose will be clear. Batman will have to hang onto the correct one to get a MacGuffin to advance the plot.

Comment: It's not really a macguffin as it upgrades one of your items. Macguffins are entirely useless.

Comment: @Merus I think it is a MacGuffin because outside of collectibles, it can't be used in new game +.

Comment: The helicopters are also a good way to find some phones ringing.